# How do I adjust cperl mode indentation in Emacs to match Moose examples?

Tags: perl, emacs, indentation, cperl-mode

How can I set up cperl mode in Emacs so that the indentation after brackets, e.g.

```
has 'name'    => (
                  is       => 'rw',
                  isa      => 'Str',
                  required => 1,
              );
```

(default indentation) becomes more like that seen in, for example, [the Moose manual](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Moose-1.08/lib/Moose/Manual/Unsweetened.pod), e.g.

```
has 'password' => (
    is  => 'rw',
    isa => 'Str',
);
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer on [the Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingPerl). Add the following to .emacs:

```
(custom-set-variables
     '(cperl-indent-parens-as-block t))
```