# How do I adjust cperl mode indentation of qw//?

Tags: perl, emacs, cperl-mode

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155468/how-do-i-adjust-cperl-mode-indentation-in-emacs-to-match-moose-examples), here's another bugbear.

I am getting

```
my @browsers = qw/
                     Firefox
                     MSIE
/;
```

but I want

```
my @browsers = qw/
    Firefox
    MSIE
/;
```

What setting in cperl mode in Emacs might I use to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't one.  x// is handled as a special case, and the information about the indent of the line that starts the statement is not available:

http://github.com/jrockway/cperl-mode/blob/mx-declare/cperl-mode.el#L3074

This can be fixed with a bit of munging in `cperl-sniff-for-indent` and `cperl-calculate-indent`.  Patch welcome!

Comment: I'll try to make a patch but my knowledge of Emacs lisp is not good.